# Time complexity and memory requirements of different set realizations

Tags: memory, data-structures, time-complexity

I want to practice data structures a bit. So let's say I have a (dynamic array, linked list, doubly linked list, search tree, hash table). So I was thinking

1. Which of them requires the least amount of memory. I'd say it's a hash table
2. Which realization requires time complexity of O(log N) when searching for values. I'd say it's a search tree.
3. Which realization is usually suitable to implement a sequence. A linked list? 
   I am just checking myself, just wanted to know if I am thinking wrong in any of those. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. least amount of memory: it's either linked-list or BST because they take only the exact memory they need while other data-structure may allocate more memory than is actually used. Double linked list is like a linked-list but requires more memory for the link "back".
2. Not sure what you mean by "realization" and indeed the search time in a BST is O(log N) assuming that the tree is balanced, and that is an important assumption!
3. Again, it's not clear what is realization or what is a sequence. Assuming that the list/array is ordered then traversing them is indeed the most efficient. And again, this is an important assumption!